# Using redis with SQL server

Tags: asp.net, redis

I am developing a web app and came across redis for key value storage. I do have a relational db SQL server. But as I have a multi tenancy system there will be separate schemas for each customer.

I was thinking how viable would it be use both redis and SQL server together? I was thinking of storing user Id and schemas so then can connect to SQL server db for that user

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly viable to use both Redis and SQL Server together.

With more details about the kinds of schema differences you expect, we might be able to provide more insight.

Comment: Schema would be per company. So all users from a company will use the same schema. So in the redis storage it would be store user login and the schema and password. If ok it would go and connect to the schema for their company. Also for a comments system which could be sat in redis with key identifier in SQL. Hope this is more clear